# I'm baking an acorn squash. How long should I bake it for?

Tags: baking, cooking-time, squash

I'm baking an acorn squash. How long should it bake for and at what temperature? I also noticed on the spaghetti squash question that those are baked sliced face down. Should acorn squash bake face down too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To roast acorn squash, set your oven to 350 and roast for about 30-35 minutes.  I normally roast cut side up, unless I am using some kind of sauce to go with it.  I find that the squash cooks to a more even color than when you place it directly against a metal pan which can develop diffrent temps across the surface.

You can also baste with some butter as long as it is face up, which is pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Lately I have been microwaving my squash and it has been coming out incredibly well.

Cut the squash in half, scoop out the seeds, put it face down on a bowl or plate with a little water, stab it with a fork a few times and do it for the same amount of time as you would a baked potato (I actually have an auto-sensing baked potato setting, which has worked perfectly).

The squash is done when a fork pierces smoothly from the outside, so you might need to add more minutes.

Or, when it is nearly done, flip it over, add a pat of butter, maybe some brown sugar, and then finish.

But we've just been eating it straight, adding butter at the table and it has been easy and exquisite.

Comment: Its good to see that there are others doing this too. I think it depends on the application though. I make this mac and cheese that uses acorn squash as a healthy additive and alternative to so much cream and cheese and microwaving works really well.

Answer (score 1):

I cut the acorn squash In half, Scoop out the seeds and put them in a baking dish or deep casserole. Drop one and a half  to 2 tablespoons of brown sugar in the well of the squash, Along with 1 tablespoon of butter.  Lay a medium Porkchop on top of the squash covering the brown sugar and butter.  Cover the casserole, and bake at 350° for one hour.

Answer (score 0):

I cut the squash up into single serving pieces - cut it in half, then take the seeds out and keeping halving all you have until the pieces are the size someone would likely eat. Brush with butter, sprinkle with nutmeg, then microwave for 3 or 4 minutes (poke to see if it's soft.) This has the advantage of not competing for limited oven space.

Comment: Kate, do you notice a flavor difference in the squash when microwaved instead of baked?

Comment: No I don't - as a result the only time I bake a squash in the oven is when I have almost nothing else in there. Since baked/roasted squash is more of a Thanksgiving thing for us, the oven is always jammed full.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things to keep in mind when microwaving squash or any food for that matter is to make sure that you let it sit for about 5 minutes or so after your done cooking it before eating. Because of the way microwaves work to heat up the food they continue to heat for that period of time. Something consumed may not feel too hot, however if it continues to heat after you ingest it your run the risk of causing burns to your esophagus and or stomach.

I think that for oven cooking 350 degrees for about 30-40 minutes would work well. This does depend on your oven slightly. As for cooking them face down it depends on how you are preparing them. If you have them in pieces for serving ( like watermelon slices ) and they are seasoned with sugar and nutmeg or whatnot I would do them face up to get some caramelizing  on the sugar. Another way to do them is season them add a little liquid to the pan and cover them. That works as well. Hope it helps.

Comment: Microwaves heat by directly exciting polar molecules into vibrating, which is heat.  The heating stops instantly when the microwaves are stopped.   There may be carry-over heat, as heat from one part of the food conducts into another part of the food, but the increase of heat energy in the food stops immediately with the cessation of microwaves.

Answer (score 0):

I cut the acorn squash In half, Scoop out the seeds and put the squash on a baking try cut side up. Drop one and a half to 2 tablespoons of brown sugar in the well of the squash, Along with 1 tablespoon of butter, some times I add dried cranberries and apples with a sprinkle of walnuts inside for a change. Bake for about an hour at 350. Should be able to stick a fork into it easily when done. We are having it this way tonight for supper.
 Oh it also helps when baking it on a tray to cut a little off the bottom so they don't roll around on the tray while putting them into the oven.